# How to run multiples VASP files named as POSCAR-XYZ

Tags: vasp, software, quantum-espresso

Is it possible to direct VASP to read a `POSCAR-xyz` file instead of reading the default POSCAR?

For example, I want to run VASP in the Quantum ESPRESSO format:

```
$/PW.x < QE.in > QE.out .
```

Here `pw.x` can read any filename that we give with a file extension of `.in`.

In the same way, I want to direct VASP to read POSCAR-xyz file instead of POSCAR.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Vasp package will not read any other name instead of `POSCAR`, The best trick is to write a small script , Here is bash script

```
for xyz in `seq  1 1 5` # change the range needed
do
mkdir $xyz
cp INCAR $xyz/
cp POTCAR $xyz/
cp POSCAR.$xyz $xyz/POSCAR
cp KPOINTS $xyz/
cd $xyz
vasp-5.4.4  # This is vasp run command add mpi if needed
cd ..
done
```

Save this as `script.sh` and run as `bash script.sh`
You can also combined `POSCAR`, `KPOINTS` and `INCAR` as single script VASP.sh same as quantum espresso.

Comment: Thanks, Pranav, So we can not use POSCAR-xyz as such as an input for VASP. We have to make it POSCAR only, right?

Comment: @kcb yes INPUT file name should be POSCAR only